# Copying an R script to PATH when installing a package (like setuptools in Python)

Tags: r, command-line, devtools

Consider this script in R that can be called from command line as `./add.R 1 2` to add two numbers:

Content of `add.R` (do `chmod +x add.R` to make it executable):

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

'usage: add.r <a> <b>' -> doc

suppressMessages(library(docopt))

opts <- docopt(doc)

print(as.double(opts[["a"]]) + as.double(opts[["b"]]))
```

Is there any way to bundle `add.R` in an R package and have the installation process copy this script to `PATH` (or update PATH) and make it available for general use? That is, I should be able to do `add.R 1 2` from anywhere.

In Python, [`setuptools`](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) lets you do this using `scripts` or `console_scripts`.

Comment: This packages seems to do so by explicitly copying files to ~/bin: https://github.com/sahilseth/funr

Comment: Similarly https://github.com/cran/ISwR/tree/master/inst/scripts adds scripts to `inst/scripts`